# Need regex to look for two words while ignoring everything in-between

Tags: c++

I've been trying to make regex find both a two digit number and the word thanks, but ignore everything in-between.

Here is my current implementation in C++, but I need the two patterns to be consolidated into one:

```
regex pattern1{R"(\d\d)"};
regex pattern2{R"(thanks)");
string to_search = "I would like the number 98 to be found and printed, thanks.";
smatch matches;
regex_search(to_search, matches, pattern1);
for (auto match : matches) {
    cout << match << endl;
}
regex_search(to_search, matches, pattern2);
for (auto match : matches) {
    cout << match << endl;
}
return 0;
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Is there any way to change ONLY the pattern and get rid of one of the for loops? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with it. It does the job just fine. However, I wanted to know if it was possible to make, say, a regex pattern3{...} that does the job of both pattern1 and pattern2 without matching everything in-between.

Comment: Also, \d{2}.*?thanks matches the following:
98 to be found and printed, thanks
When I want:
98 thanks

Comment: So add the proper capture groups? e.g.: `(\d{2}).*?(thanks)`

Comment: Well, it still matches everything between 98 and thanks.

Comment: Then you are extracting the wrong result, but since you don't provide the code for how you are matching and reading the result we can't help you

Comment: Ah I understand. I'll edit the question then.